# Individual Emails missing "Message-Id: header"

Tags: civimail, email

I'm testing our emails with Mail-Tester.com and it's showing that when sending individual email messages to Contacts, the emails are missing a "Message-Id: header".

How can I change this?  It doesn't appear to happen when sending bulk email, just individual emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under administer - civimail - civimail component settings there is an option for "Enable CiviMail to generate Message-ID header"

Comment: thanks - it worked!